# Scatter plot with logical indexing

Tags: python, indexing, list-comprehension

I have a 100x2 array D and a 100x1 array c (with entries +/- 1) I'm trying to make a scatter plot of the columns in D corresponding to c = 1.

I tried something like this: `plt.scatter(D[0][c==1],D[1][c==1])` but it throws up `IndexError: too many indices for array`

I'm aware that I've use list comprehension or something of that sort. I'm fairly new to Python and hence struggling with the format.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are those "arrays" `D` and `c` both numpy arrays? That matters here.

Comment: @RoryDaulton: Yes. When I do type(D), type(c), it gives numpy.ndarray

Comment: Can you give the output to `D.shape` please, you give a shape that has 100 rows, but are talking about columns.

Comment: D.shape is (100,2) c.shape is (100,1). When I execute your code below, c is (100, ). Hence it's throwing an error.

Comment: @db18 I'll update the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Concept***

You can use `np.where` to select only rows from `D` that are `1` in your array `C`:

```
D = np.array([[0.25, 0.25], [0.75, 0.75]])
C = np.array([1, 0])
```

Using `np.where`, we can select only rows that are `1` in `C`:

```
>>> D[np.where(C==1)]
array([[0.25, 0.25]])
```

***Example*** On your actual data:

```
D = np.random.randn(100, 2)
C = np.random.randint(0, 2, (100, 1))

valid = D[np.where(C.ravel()==1)]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(valid[:, 0], valid[:, 1])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I used valid = D[np.where(c==1)[0]] to make it compatible with my c shape of (100,1)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the shapes, I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy for this (assuming you have two numpy arrays, otherwise you can convert them into numpy arrays):

```
import numpy as np

c_ones = np.where(c == 1) # Finds all indices where c == 1
d_0 = D[0][c_ones]
d_1 = D[1][c_ones]
```

Then you can plot d_0, d_1 as normal.

For converting your lists if needed,

```
C_np = np.asarray(c)
D_np = np.asarray(D)
```

And then perform `np.where` on C_np as shown above.

Would this solve your issue?